# DataBindingUtil findBinding(View view) vs getBinding(View view)

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

What is the intended purpose of the method `findBinding(View view)`?

I've been working with the Data Binding Library beta release.
There's no official reference documentation available for the individual classes yet, so I've been looking through the source code to see what methods we can access.

The DataBindingUtil class has two methods that sound like they'd do similar things:

- `public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T findBinding(View view)`
- `public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T getBinding(View view)`

The second method `getBinding` is just a utility method that calls the `ViewDataBinding` class' `getBinding` method.

The first method `findBinding` is a little more unclear to follow and determine its purpose. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, the docs are missing from the webpage but they should be in the sdk maven repository.

The difference is that, find binding will traverse the parents whereas getBinding will return `null` if the given view is not a binding root. Here are the docs:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the binding responsible for the given View. If <code>view</code> is not a
 * binding layout root, its parents will be searched for the binding. If there is no binding,
 * <code>null</code> will be returned.
 * <p>
 * This differs from {@link #getBinding(View)} in that findBinding takes any view in the
 * layout and searches for the binding associated with the root. <code>getBinding</code>
 * takes only the root view.
 *
 * @param view A <code>View</code> in the bound layout.
 * @return The ViewDataBinding associated with the given view or <code>null</code> if
 * view is not part of a bound layout.
 */
public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T findBinding(View view) {

/**
 * Retrieves the binding responsible for the given View layout root. If there is no binding,
 * <code>null</code> will be returned. This uses the DataBindingComponent set in
 * {@link #setDefaultComponent(DataBindingComponent)}.
 *
 * @param view The root <code>View</code> in the layout with binding.
 * @return The ViewDataBinding associated with the given view or <code>null</code> if
 * either the view is not a root View for a layout or view hasn't been bound.
 */
public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T getBinding(View view) {
```

Comment: Its been a while, but no proper docs are available for data binding! I see many blog posts on medium and g+ for data binding. You should add it to docs first other than blogs first.